# Find the first row result of query in ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to create this query with ssis component:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Date_Execution
FROM Action
WHERE Action_Ref=1
ORDER BY Date_Execution
```

Can I do that without using script component?

---

**Update**

This query must be included in a flow task. I need it to calculate a field of a table I'm creating.

Comment: Help me understand your question. I assume putting that query in an Execute SQL Task or an ADO/OLE DB Data Source is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I want to know if it's possible to do that with a lookup component for example. I fails to do the "TOP 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Aggregate transform. If you insist on starting with the full table contents then use a Conditional Split transform to get those rows that meet your WHERE clause, then use the Aggregate transform to get the minimum Date_Execution from the remaining rows.

Or just be reasonable about it and use a SQL execute task. The database server will be much more efficient than SSIS at getting this result.